# Can you identify this New England Patriots player from the 2004 superbowl?

Tags: nfl

A friend of mine met him in LA, saw the Superbowl ring, and got a photo with him. She didn't get his name, though, but during their conversation she learned he played with the Patriots in the 2004 Superbowl (i.e. 2003 season)

[image]

Comment: We can start by narrowing it down. There are only 53 players on an NFL roster. How big was this person, approximately? That could help determine what position he might have played.

Comment: Good thought. He is approximately 5'11". Not sure on the position he played though.

Comment: OK, I haven't gone through the whole roster, but it might be [David Givens](http://i.imgur.com/6XRYWRG.jpg). Hard to tell with this lighting.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a photo-finder question, a type of source/research request. Meta discussion in regards to photo-finder questions can be found [here](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/476/is-photo-finder-type-questions-on-topic).